# Sign jar files without JDK's jarsigner

Tags: java, android, jarsigner

I created an android app for a firm which is going to deliver signed APKs to its costumer after integrating a different license in the apk for each one (security measure to prevent sharing app). I created a batch file that signs the .apk file as follows

```
jarsigner.exe -keystore res\KEY.keystore -storepass s***** -keypass s***** temp.zip KEY
```

This works fine on a machine with JDK installed, but to make it as light as possible is there any standalone jar signer on windows that does the same job without JDK?

I searched on stackoverflow but all solution uses JDK.

Comment: Would solutions involving the JRE, instead of the JDK, be suitable? If so apksigner (from modern Android SDK build tools) looks like it would be appropriate.

Comment: @tallungulate Yes, JRE from android SDK worked without installation, but I should copy all JRE directory (100 Mb) and include it with the licensing tool, I think I will use it if I didn't find a light solution. Thanks!

Comment: So with the JRE installed, you should be to copy apksigner.jar out of the Android SDK and use it with java -jar apksigner.jar sign ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s right that you need JDK for it, but you can use an exe compressor, which will install both the JDK along with the files you need, so the user will not notice it. It’ll be just a part of the installation. Google for “Exe maker” and find the one you are most comfortable with.